# Как вернуть новый массив из forEach как результат?

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach, ecmascript-6

Задача - добавить в каждому элементу массива нолик при помощи `forEach` и сделать так, чтобы функция вернула новый массив. На входе -  `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` на выходе `[01,02,03,04,05,06,07]`

Я приведу фрагмент кода.

```
    const myArr = () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    const log = (result) => console.log(result)

    const addZeros = arr => arr.forEach(x => {
                    return (x < 10) ? 
                    "0" + x : 
                    x               
                })

 log(addZeros(myArr())) // undefined
```

Я понимаю, что `addZeros` не возвращает и не формирует массив, хотелось бы понять как это сделать на данном примере.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ForEach` проводит операции над каждым элементов массива в цикле, при этом массив не возвращается.

Вам следовало использовать `map`, который может возвратить результат как новый массив:

```js
const myArr = () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
const log = (result) => console.log(result)

const addZeros = arr => arr.map(x => {
    return (x < 10) ? 
    "0" + x : 
    x               
})

log(addZeros(myArr())) // undefined
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @RomanTselenko Если мой ответ помог вам вы можете пометить его как принятый, нажав на галку слева от ответа под кнопками для голосования.